# Drive letters messed up after migrating Windows to different partition

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, filesystems

I used to have two different installations of Windows – one old and the other newly installed. I wanted to get rid of the old installation, and to do so, I copied the contents of the new Windows partition onto the old Windows partition (using Gparted live USB) and formatted the new Windows partition.

Since the boot files got deleted in the process, I booted from the Windows Recovery CD and rebuilt the BCD (boot configuration data).

Now, when I try to boot into Windows, the booting process occurs fine, but I cannot log in as a user (Windows simply logs out as soon as I press log in). To find the reason for this strange behaviour, I tried to boot in safe mode, and found that the drive letters got messed up in the process. The system drive is labelled **D:** and the other partition (now empty) is called **C:** drive. As a result, most of the programs have stopped working.

What can I do to restore the original drive letters?

Answer (score 1):

We need to edit the Windows Registry to change the drive letter of the system drive. The required steps are as follows –

1. Start Windows in safe mode.
2. Press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to start the Run tool, and type **regedit.exe**.
3. Go to the registry key: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices**
4. Now, we need to free up the drive letter **C:**. To do so, right-click on **\DosDevices\C:** and click rename.
5. Rename the key to an unused drive letter, **DosDevices\Z:** to free up the drive letter **C:**.
6. Since the actual system drive has the label **D:**, rename **DosDevices\D:** to **DosDevices\C:**.
7. Finally, rename **DosDevices\Z:** as **DosDevices\D:**.
8. Quit the Registry Editor and restart the computer.

The proper drive letters will be restored after the reboot.

Source: [Microsoft Support – Article 223188](http://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/223188)

---

(Solved and answered my own question for lack of any other answer.)